Question on approximation of norms
Suppose that $E\in Int[L_{p},L_{q}]$ for some $1<p<q<\infty$ and $E$ is $w$-concave with $1<w<\infty$. It is well-known that for each $r\geq w$, we have $E=L_{r}\odot F_{r}$ for some symmetric space $F_{r}$. Do we have $\lim_{r\to \infty}\|f\|_{F_{r}}=\|f\|_{E}$ for $f\in L_{\infty}$?
PS: All spaces are assumed to be defined on the closed interval $[0,1]$ equipped with the Lebesgue measure. The space $E$ is assumed to have $w$-concave constant $1$.
All notations are explained as follows: $E\in Int[L_{p},L_{q}]$ means that $L_{q}\subseteq E\subseteq L_{p}$ and any bounded linear operator $T:L_{p}\to L_{p}$ and $T(L_{q})\subseteq L_{q}$, then we have $T(E)\subseteq E$ and $\|T\|_{E\to E}\leq C\max\{\|T\|_{L_{q}\to L_{q}},\|T\|_{L_{p}\to L_{p}}\}$.
Let $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ be two symmetric Banach function spaces, and then the pointwise product space of $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ is defined by
$$X_{1}\odot X_{2}=\{f:f=x_{1}\cdot x_{2}~\mbox{with }x_{1}\in X_{1},~x_{2}\in X_{2}\},$$
equipped with the norm
$$\|f\|_{X_{1}\odot X_{2}}=\inf\{\|x_{1}\|_{X_{1}}\|x_{2}\|_{X_{2}}:f=x_{1}\cdot x_{2},~x_{j}\in X_{j},~j=1,~2\}.$$
A symmetric Banach function space $X$ is said to be $0<w<\infty$ concave if there exists a constant $c>0$ such that
$$\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n}\|f_{j}\|^{w}_{X}\right)^{1/w}\leq c \left\|\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n}|f_{j}|^{w}\right)^{1/w}\right\|_{X},$$
for every finite sequence $\{f_{j}\}_{j=1}^{n}$ in $X$. The smallest constant $c>0$, such that the previous inequality holds for any finite sequences, is called the $w$-concave constant.

More precisely, $F_{r}=M(L_{r};E)={g\in L_{0}[0,1]:gf\in E,~\forall f\in L_{r}}$ the space of multiplication operators from $L_{r}$ to $E$, equipped with the norm $|g|{M(L{r};E)}=\sup{|gf|{E},~|f|{L_{r}}\leq 1}$.

There seems to be a lot of nonstandard notation and notions in your question which will make it hard for people to answer and to learn. It would be much improved if you could clarify a bit. (What is $Int[L_p,L_q]$, what is $w$-concave, what do you mean by $\odot$?)

I have added an explanation of the notations.
